# Centering dots in latex

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

How can I center the cdots on the third line to the surrounding equations?

```
$F(-\infty, x_2,\cdots, x_n)=C\big(0,F_2(x_2),\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big)=0$,\\
$F(x_1,-\infty,\cdots, x_n)=C\big(F_1(x_1),0,\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big)=0$,\\
$\cdots$ \\
$F(x_1,x_2,\cdots,-\infty)=C\big(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2),\cdots, 0\big)=0$.\
```

like so:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        ...
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using multiple inline equations (`$ ... $`), you could use one of the environments for multi line equations provided by `amsmath`, namely `gather*`. See the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) manual for descriptions of the various environments it provides.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
F(-\infty, x_2,\cdots, x_n)=C\big(0,F_2(x_2),\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big)=0,\\
F(x_1,-\infty,\cdots, x_n)=C\big(F_1(x_1),0,\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big)=0,\\
\cdots \\
F(x_1,x_2,\cdots,-\infty)=C\big(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2),\cdots, 0\big)=0
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't really like this solution, but it appears (see comments) to be sufficient:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}  % for creating dummy text

\begin{document}
\kant[4]

\noindent$\begin{gathered}
F(-\infty, x_2,\cdots, x_n)=C\big(0,F_2(x_2),\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big)=0,\\
F(x_1,-\infty,\cdots, x_n)=C\big(F_1(x_1),0,\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big)=0,\\
\cdots \\
F(x_1,x_2,\cdots,-\infty)=C\big(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2),\cdots, 0\big)=0
\end{gathered}
$

\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer when I wrote mine, sorry.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap No problem.

Comment: This does work, however it centers the equations on the page where as I would like to keep them right-aligned. Is there a way to align the gather* to the right?

Comment: @yenta Right-aligned? Your document is RTL? Don't have any brilliant ideas. You could replace `gather*` with `gathered`, and put dollar signs before and after, i.e. `$\begin{gathered} ... \end{gathered}$`, I suppose. I really don't know what is the best way of doing this though.

Comment: \end{gathered}$ \\ and it worked. I would prefer it to be centered but the professor I am working under prefers it to be right-aligned in this specific case.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that you want inline-maths (the `$ ... $` in your examples)? In a situation like this, what is often preferable are displayed-math environments. For instance, if you want every equation to be centered, you could write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  F(-\infty, x_2,\ldots, x_n) = C\big(0,F_2(x_2),\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big) = 0 , \\
  F(x_1,-\infty,\ldots, x_n) = C\big(F_1(x_1),0,\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big) = 0 , \\
  \cdots \\
  F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,-\infty) = C\big(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2),\cdots, 0\big) = 0 .
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you would prefer the equations (and the dots) to be aligned on the first equals-sign in each case, you could write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  F(-\infty, x_2,\ldots, x_n) &= C\big(0,F_2(x_2),\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big) = 0 , \\
  F(x_1,-\infty,\ldots, x_n) &= C\big(F_1(x_1),0,\cdots, F_n(x_n)\big) = 0 , \\
  &\cdots \\
  F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,-\infty) &= C\big(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2),\cdots, 0\big) = 0 .
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, you may wish to replace the centered dots `\cdots` with vertical dots `\vdots`; and if you would like these equations to be numbered, use either `gather` (instead of `gather*`) or `align` (instead of `align*`).